# How do you keep vscode from inserting extra spaces

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-diff

I have made a pull request to a library on github. I am using vscode as the editor. It seems that vscode is removing a space after each comma created unnecessary changes in the diff. How can I stop this from happening.

I have a `.vscode/settings.json` with

```json
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "editor.insertSpaces": false,
```

This is what I am getting in my diff. Notice the extra space after the comma on line 55.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the above workspace config was not being respected. I had `editor.insertSpace:true" in the vscode global config. Taking it out solved.